# browser fails to connect to mail server

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, phpmailer, mail-server

I'm using phpstorm to run my PHP code which is meant to send emails using the PHP mail function

```php
$mailto = "olo@yahoo.com"; 
//$mailto = $_POST['mail_to'];
$subject = "Your password"; 
$message = "<p>Hello Homer,</p>
<p>Thanks for registering.</p>
<p>Your password is: <b>springfield</b></p>
"; 
$from = "myweatherbe@gmail.com"; 
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n"; $headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n"; 
//Send email 
mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers); 
// Inform the
user echo " Thanks for registering! We have just sent you an email with your password.";
```

when I run the code in phpstorm it sends the mail but when I run it on my web browser I get:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in

I have gone through several videos and sites and I'm yet to find anything that can help me solve this problem

the server I'm using is Xampp

Comment: Do you have a smtp server running on your localhost? It is possible that PHPStorm starts some servers and services.

Comment: i'm using xampp not sure its an smtp server  but it allows me send mails when i run my php code in phpstorm

Comment: Did you check `php.ini` as suggested in the warning?

Comment: yes, I did. I don't think that's the problem though because the mail sends when run my code in the phpstrom ide but when run it through the browser  i get that error

Comment: as far as I know, there is no mailserver enabled by default with XAMPP, consider FakeSMTP for example: http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/
(just "start" server whenever you want work with local mailer)